# Compute $ \int_{0}^{+\infty} \left( \frac{\ln(x)}{e^x}\right)^2 dx $

Tags: real-analysis, integration

How can I compute this integral?
$$
\int_{0}^{+\infty} \left( \frac{\ln(x)}{e^x}\right)^2 dx
$$

Comment: What do you mean by compute? Do you want a closed-form formula?

Comment: $\int_{0}^{\infty} \bigl( \frac{\ln x}{e^x}\bigr)^2 dx=\frac{1}{12}\pi ^2+\frac{1}{2} (\gamma_{\rm Euler} +\ln 2)^2$

Comment: I don't need the result but rather the method, I used Integration by parts
 but had problems with $ \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{e^{-2x}}{x} ln(x) $

Comment: @mathouv, look my below linked answer, I already asked [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3756933/156150) yesterday

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Let
$$f(a):=\int_0^\infty x^{a-1}e^{-2x}\,dx.$$
Then
$$f''(1)=\int_0^\infty \ln^2x\,e^{-2x}\,dx,$$
which is the integral in question.

On the other hand, $f(a)=2^{-a}\,\Gamma(a)$, and hence
the integral in question is
$$f''(1)=\frac{\ln^2 2}2 - \Gamma'(1)\ln2
+ \Gamma''(1)/2
=\frac{\pi^2}{12}+ \frac{(\gamma +\ln2)^2}2=1.6293\dots,$$
where $\gamma=0.57721\dots$ is the Euler gamma constant.

(The second equality in the latter display follows because $\Gamma'(1)=-\gamma$ and $\Gamma''(1)=\gamma^2+\pi^2/6$. In turn, the latter two equalities can be obtained using the last two displays in Section [Recurrence relation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polygamma_function#Recurrence_relation).)

Comment: Is this the technique referred to as differentiation under the integral sign?

Comment: $f(a)$ is a Mellin transform, right? Is this often used to compute seemingly tricky integrals?

Comment: @BenCrowell : Yes, of course.

Comment: @SylvainJULIEN : Yes, $f$ is the Mellin transform of $e^{-2\cdot}$. I am very far from an expert in the Mellin transform, though.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**: you may try $n=2$ and follow in general this :\begin{align} \int_0^\infty \left(\frac{\log(x)}{e^x}\right)^n\,dx&=\int_0^\infty e^{-nx}\log^n(x)\,dx\\\\ &=\frac1n\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}\log^{n-k}(n)\int_0^\infty e^{-x}\log^n(x)\,dx\\\\ &=\frac1n\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}\log^{n-k}(n) \left.\left(\frac{d^n \Gamma(x+1)}{dx^n}\right)\right|_{x=0} \end{align}

For more information check answers of [my question here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3756958/156150)

For more clarification according to the answer of @Nikunj, try $n=2$ using this steps in general: Let $$I(a) = \int_0^\infty e^{-nx}x^a\,dx$$
$$\implies \frac{d^nI(a)}{da^n} = \int_0^\infty e^{-nx}x^a(\ln x)^n\,dx$$
Put $nx \rightarrow v$ in the first integral to get:
$$I(a) = \frac1{n^{1+a}}\int_0^\infty e^{-v}v^a\,dv$$
$$\implies I(a) = \frac{\Gamma(1+a)}{n^{1+a}}$$
Now $$\implies \frac{d^nI(a)}{da^n}\bigg|_{a=0} = \frac{d^n}{da^n}\left(\frac{\Gamma(1+a)}{n^{1+a}}\right)\bigg|_{a=0}$$
Which evaluates to:
$$\frac1{n}\sum_{k=0}^n(-1)^k\binom{n}{k}\Gamma^{(n-k)}(1+a)\ln^k(n)\bigg|_{a=0}$$
Where $\Gamma^{(n-k)}(1+a)$ is the $(n-k)$th derivative of the Gamma function.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for $n = 2$. Do you mean to have $\displaystyle \frac1n\sum_{k=0}^n(-1)^k\binom{n}{k}\log^{n-k}(n)\int_0^\infty e^{-x}\log^k(x)\,dx$?

Comment: @ChipHurst,  I had a wrong linked question, it fixed now , I already asked this question yesterday [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3756933/156150)